# JQuery daterangepicker Some function should be executed on some random dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

```js
    function addtoday(){
            alert("Today");
        }
        function addyesterday(){
            alert("Yesterday");
        }
        function  lastweek1(){
            alert("lastweek");
        }
        function  last30days1(){
            alert("last30days");
        }
        function  presentmonth1(){
            alert("this month");
        }
        function  lastmonth1(){
            alert("lastmonth");
        }
        function randomfunction(){
            alert("randommmmmm");
        }
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});


$('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {


    if (picker.chosenLabel == "Today") {
        addtoday();
    }
    if (picker.chosenLabel == "Yesterday") {
        addyesterday();
    }
    if (picker.chosenLabel == "Last 7 Days") {
        lastweek1();
    }
    if (picker.chosenLabel == "Last 30 Days") {
        last30days1();
    }
    if (picker.chosenLabel == "This Month") {
        presentmonth1();
    }
    if (picker.chosenLabel == "Last Month") {
        lastmonth1();
    }
    else if(setDate == "10/02/2018" && setDate == "10/20/2018") {
        randomfunction();
    }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F6KW.png)I am able to execute functions while i click on labels .Same way i should be able to execute functions while i click on a random date on my calendar

```
$(function () {
var start = moment().subtract(6, 'days');
var end = moment();


function cb(start, end) {
    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

}

$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    minDate: moment().subtract(365, 'days'),
    maxDate: moment(),
    ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment(),],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days'),],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
    },
},

    cb)
cb(start, end);
});
$('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {


if (picker.chosenLabel == "Today") {
    addtoday();
}
else if (picker.chosenLabel == "Yesterday") {
    addyesterday();
}
else if (picker.chosenLabel == "Last 7 Days") {
    lastweek1();
}
else if (picker.chosenLabel == "Last 30 Days") {
    last30days1();
}
else if (picker.chosenLabel == "This Month") {
    presentmonth1();
}
else if (picker.chosenLabel == "Last Month") {
    lastmonth1();
}
else if(picker.startDate == "10/02/2018" && picker.endDate == "10/20/2018"){

   randomfunction();
}
});
```

I am able to execute all functions but I  am unable to execute randomfunction in my code,and can i store those dates in variables so that i can change it dynamically

Comment: Am I missing something? Your prior `else if` conditions will be met before the randomfunction(); so it never enters that branch. Change it to an `if`

Comment: But i am able to execute all else if functions except the last

Comment: Just go to dev tools and put a break on the final 'else if' my bet is the conditions are never met or it falls into a prior `else if`

Comment: I have changed all "else if" to "if" still all functions run perfectly except the last function,I think some problem with the last condition that is start and end dates,please help me out with the condtion "picker.startDate" or something else might be used instead

Comment: What is the value of picker.startDate? have you checked it is "10/02/2018"?

Comment: i have updated an image at the top please check.

Comment: Right... I know you've selected those dates. What I'm saying is, what is the exact value of picker.setDate? do you know it is a string in the format "10/02/2018"?! It could be in another format like iso, dd/mm/yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy, etc...

Comment: No Idea,but i tried changing the formats too,but still if u have any clue please ....

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: I can't debug your code for you if I don't know what variable values your conditions are equating to

Comment: please run on snippet,its working in my browser only last function is not working

Comment: The snippet doesn't run

Comment: it runs now please check

Comment: "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: setDate is not defined",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't convert the date your comparing from Epoch format.

**EDIT:** Also the endDate in your range is set to the end of that day, e.g a time of 23:59. I've amended it so that when you do the comparison it is set to the start of that day (00:00). That may not be what you want but it is simple to amend.

```js
    function addtoday(){
            alert("Today");
        }
        function addyesterday(){
            alert("Yesterday");
        }
        function  lastweek1(){
            alert("lastweek");
        }
        function  last30days1(){
            alert("last30days");
        }
        function  presentmonth1(){
            alert("this month");
        }
        function  lastmonth1(){
            alert("lastmonth");
        }
        function randomfunction(){
            alert("randommmmmm");
        }
$(function() {
    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});


$('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {

    if (picker.chosenLabel == "Today") {
        addtoday();
    }
    if (picker.chosenLabel == "Yesterday") {
        addyesterday();
    }
    if (picker.chosenLabel == "Last 7 Days") {
        lastweek1();
    }
    if (picker.chosenLabel == "Last 30 Days") {
        last30days1();
    }
    if (picker.chosenLabel == "This Month") {
        presentmonth1();
    }
    if (picker.chosenLabel == "Last Month") {
        lastmonth1();
    }

    if(picker.startDate == toEpochDate("10/02/2018") && toEpochDate(picker.endDate) == toEpochDate("10/20/2018")) {
        randomfunction();
    }
});

function toEpochDate(date){
    var d = new Date(date);
    d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    return d.getTime();
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: October 2, 2018 - October 20, 2018 yet I never get the random with this

Comment: Thanks a lot for your work but random function is yet not executed please check

Comment: hang on my bad... will sort @vaseem

Comment: Can I make the dates random like any date, That is whatever date range I click on the calendar it should be taken as input(not only "10/02/2018" to "10/20/2018") and execute in that if statement which you have corrected @ Sean T

Comment: So you want random to fire all the time when dates are picked? Or do you want to be able to compare to any date in the if statement